# Operation with data frame with loop for

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

i have this two data frame:  `df(A`) (nrow=10,ncol=2), and `df(B)` (nrow=3,ncol=2).

```
 df(A)                    df(B)
col1  col2            col1 col2                     
1      2                13  34 
3      5                22  56 
5      7                30  42 
6      9                 
9      11                 
4.5   5.5                 
21    6.7                 
3.5   5                   
6     7.9                 
67     4
```

It's possible to multiply and sum each value in df(A) in this mode? :
   EXAMPLE:

```
A[1,1]*B[1,1] + A[1,1]*B[1,2] + A[1,1]*B[1,3]= 1*13+1*22+1*30= 65 
A[2,1]*B[1,1] + A[2,1]*B[1,2] + A[2,1]*B[1,3]= 3*13+3*22+3*30 = 195
and so on for all row in A&col1 for B$col1
```

the same for A$col2 and B$col2

```
A[1,2]*B[1,1] + A[1,2]*B[1,2] + A[1,2]*B[1,3]= 2*34+2*56+2*42= 264
A[2,2]*B[1,1] + A[2,2]*B[1,2] + A[2,2]*B[1,3]= 5*34+5*56+5*42=660
and so on for all row in A&col2 for B$col2
```

The expected result is a `df(C)` with 2 col and 10 row.

I tempted with `apply`, but it work for the entire row or the entire colum. This example is semplify, but my true `df` is biggest, with 10 column and more than 1000 row. 
It's possible with loop `for` ?
I tempted with  loop `for` in this manner:

```
temp <- rep(NA,3)

my_matrix <- matrix(0,ncol=ncol(A),nrow=nrow(A))

for (i in 1:nrow(A)){
  for (j in 1:3){
    temp(j) <- A(i+j-1)*B(i+j-1)
  }
  my_matrix(i) <- sum(temp)
}
```

but R responde :`Error: could not find function "A"`or

```
attempt to apply non-function`
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: Could you please explain better what you mean?
Do you want to multiply A$col1 * B$col1 subject to conditions in A$col3 and B$col3.

Comment: Ii edited my previous post, now i hope the question it's better and clear. If you can help me thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I may be completely wrong on that, but I would go with something like this:

### 1) Create grid of all combinations

`Grid<-expand.grid(1:5,1:5)`

#### Edit: matching your definition of "contrary product"

### 2) Subset your dataframes on the values of interest

```
result<-matrix()
for(i in 1:nrow(Grid)){
   First<-A[A[,3]==Grid[i,1],1]*B[B[,3]==4-Grid[i,2],1] ### Gets the first column product, and does the "Contrary product" that you mention in comments
   Second<-A[A[,3]==Grid[i,1],2]*B[B[,3]==4-Grid[i,2],2] ### Gets the second column product
   result<-rbind(result,cbind(First,Second,Grid[i,1],Grid[i,2])) ### Keep track of the values you used for subsetting
}
```

Comment: Hi, i edited my previous post, now i hope the question it's better and  clear. If you can help me thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you mistake rows and lines in your new code: dataframe B only has 2 columns, yet you use "B[1,3]" in your example.